# reading and writing to same file with jar

Tags: java, file, jar

So, here's the problem: I'm working on a Java program that reads from a .csv file, and constructs objects out of it.  I'm using InputStream, InputStreamReader, and BufferedReader to read the file. The IDE I'm using is NetBeans and the file being read is in the src directory.  A quick note, for your convenience, I hardcoded the filename, so that you would understand how it's actually being read. In my actual program, the filename is being passed in as a parameter of the method. Anyways, it seems to work fine in the IDE.  But when I create a JAR, it doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
    public void readFile(filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

                is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.csv"); 
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                //fr = new FileReader(filename);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String info;

        while ((info = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
                        String[] tokens = info.split(",");
                        Object object = new Object();
                        object.setProperty(tokens[0]);
                        object.setAnotherProperty(tokens[1]);
                        object.setSomeOtherProperty(tokens[2]);
         }

         } 
catch (FileNotFoundException f) 
    {
        f.getMessage();
    } 
catch (IOException ioe)
     {
        ioe.getMessage();
     } 
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob)
     {
        //;
     } 
catch (NullPointerException npe)
     {
        //;
     }
finally
     {
        br.close();
        isr.close();
        is.close();
     }
```

My method to update the file looks like this(once again, the filename has been hardcoded so you could better understand what's going on):

```
public void updateRoom(String filename, String property1, string property2, string property3) throws FileNotFoundException
```

{

```
        for (Objects o : objects)
        {
            if (o.getProperty().equals(property1))
            {
                o.setProperty(property1);
                o.setAnotherProperty(property2);
                o.setSomeOtherProperty(property3);
            }
        }

        File file = new File("file.csv");
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (Object o : objects)
        {

            pr.println(o.getProperty() + "," +
                       o.getAnotherProperty() + "," +
                       o.getSomeOtherProperty())
        }
        pr.close();
 }
```

The problem is that the .JAR reads the file when I run it, but instead of writing to the SAME file, it simply creates a new one and writes to that one.  It's a problem because every time I run the program again, the properties and values remain unchanged.  It's NOT reading from the newly-created file.  It's still reading from the original file, but it's writing to a new file.

I want to READ AND WRITE to the same file. That way, if I close the program and run it again, it will have the new properties/values already loaded in.

Comment: It is not really advised to write in the classpath directly... There are APIs to read/write to files "related" to your application, why don't you use that instead?

Comment: You can't write to an entry of a jar file. `getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");` reads from the file.txt resource of the classpath, i.e. from the file.txt entry inside the jar file. `new File("file.txt")` represents the file.txt file of the current directory, i.e. the directory from which the `java`command is executed. They're not the same thing at all.

Comment: I kind of understand. You're saying that my program is currently READING FROM a file that is somehow "embedded" or located WITHIN the jar file, but it is WRITING TO a file that is located within the same directory that the jar file is located, but not within the jar file itself. With that being said, now I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  How can I ensure that the JAR reads from and writes to the same file?

Comment: Use the file as read-only _resource_, as _template_ to create a writable file in the user's directory. (`getClass().getResource("/...")` / `getResourceAsStream("/...")`).

Comment: Joop Eggen, could you elaborate a bit for me?

I'm a bit of a novice.